# running (registering) prefect flows with parameters on schedule

Tags: python, etl, prefect

In **prefect** I would like to run flows with parameters on schedule.
That sounds very natural to pass parameters, e.g. db credentials, right?

I have created a flow with parameters that runs well as `prefect run -p flow.py --param db_config_path=somepath`, now I would like to register it as `prefect register --project project_name --path flow.py --name somename` (with server started and agent running) to run on schedule.

However the server says:

`graphql_1   | {"severity": "ERROR", "name": "prefect-server.api.flows", "message": "Failed to set schedule to active while creating flow (flow_id={flow_id}).", "exc_info": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/prefect-server/src/prefect_server/api/flows.py", line 285, in create_flow\n    await api.flows.set_schedule_active(flow_id=flow_id)\n  File "/prefect-server/src/prefect_server/api/flows.py", line 564, in set_schedule_active\n    raise ValueError("Can not schedule a flow that has required parameters.")\nValueError: Can not schedule a flow that has required parameters."}`

Moreover I found this:

https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/issues/380

So it seems that flows with parameters are out of **prefect** paradigm? How do I pass db creds to the flows in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. DB creds should ideally be secrets instead of parameters. On Prefect Cloud, you can store the secret with us and load it using the `PrefectSecret` task. On Server, you need to store [local](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/concepts/secrets.html#setting-local-secrets) secrets. You can also see more on that [here](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-to-set-secrets-e-g-github-access-token-on-server/70)
2. On the parameters, you can also do `required=False` so that you can register without a default.
3. Parameters defaults on clocks/schedule don’t fulfill the requirement of having a default parameter because you can still trigger ad-hoc runs that would then not have any filled value.

Comment: thanks a lot! 
1. Ok - db creds will be secrets, makes sense.
2. I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting. Where would I do `required=False` ? Let's say there are ingestion /transformation parameters I don't want to hard-code, like the size of the page for pagination tasks, or a parameter specified what docs to filter out. So I believe the use case is real.

Comment: `required=False` can be passed to the Parameter. For example,
`x = Parameter("x", default=3, required=False)` required is True by default. If you set it to false, you don't have to hardcode anything. Or am I missing something?